# Размер sizeof() указателя на структуру

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
struct privateNumber
{
    int number;
    int number2;
    privateNumber* next;/// указатель на следующий элемент
};
privateNumber *address = NULL;
void addPrivateNumber(int getNumber)
{
    privateNumber *ptr = new privateNumber;
    cout << sizeof(ptr) << endl; /// В чем разница?
    cout << sizeof(*ptr) << endl; /// Объясните выдает по разному
    ptr -> number = getNumber;
    ptr -> next = address;
    address = ptr;
}
int main()
{
    addPrivateNumber(100);
}
```

В чем разница между `sizeof(ptr)` и `sizeof(*ptr)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, что разность в типах операндов, используемых в выражениях с оператором `sizeof`

Операнд этого выражения

```
sizeof(ptr)
```

как следует их объявления переменной `ptr`

```
privateNumber *ptr = ...
```

имеет тип указателя на структуру `privateNumber`. Указатели обычно в памяти занимают 4 или 8 байтов в зависимости от операционной среды, где запускается программа.

Операнд данного выражения

```
 sizeof(*ptr)
```

то есть `*ptr` также как следует из объявления переменной `ptr` имеет тип `struct privateNumber`. Соответственно, оператор `sizeof` вернет размер именно этой структуры.

Как видно из объявления структуры ее размер значительно больше размера указателя, так как эта структура помимо других членов включает в себя также и указатель на структуру

```
struct privateNumber
{
    int number;
    int number2;
    privateNumber* next;/// указатель на следующий элемент
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: я впихивал в структуру тип char и в итоге получилось 16байт, почему 16байт если char всего 1?(без char было 12)

Comment: потому что есть такое понятие как выравнивание. То есть, если есть два поля типа char, то первый char занимает нулевой байт, потом три байта пустышки-заглушки, потом в 4 байте сохраняется второй char и снова 3 байта заглушки. Это делается с целью оптимизации.

Comment: @MaximPro Я не знаю, как вы там впихивали char, но структура в любом случае должна быть выравнена на границу, соответствующую самому строгому выравниванию своего члена. Если ваша структура, например, имеет один член типа char и один указатель на структуру, и если размер указателя равен 8 байтам, то структура  будет дополнена еще 7 байтами, чтобы ее размер был кратен 8, то есть размеру указателя.

Comment: ну было так(12):
struct privateNumber
{
    int number;
    int number2;
    privateNumber* next;/// указатель на следующий элемент
};
стал(16):
struct privateNumber
{
    int number;
    int number2;
    char symbol;
    privateNumber* next;/// указатель на следующий элемент
};

Comment: @MaximPro Или если без char размер структуры был равен 12 байтам, то есть выравнивание структуры было кратно 4, то при добавлении одного объекта типа char структура была дополнена еще 3 байтами, чтобы ее размер снова был кратен 4.

Comment: где можно про это почитать? впервые слышу о выравнивании

Comment: @MaximPro Да, не все книги могут затрагивать данную спецификацию языка. Я даже не знаю, в какой книге об этом говорится явно.  Поэтому поищите в гугл по  ключевым словам C++ alignment и alignof

Comment: ага спасибо.....

Comment: @MaximPro Советую скачать бесплатную книгу Брюса Эккеля, правда, она на английском языке "Thinking in C++" http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/

Answer (score 4):

В одном случае (`sizeof(ptr)`) будет размер указателя (а это 4 байта, но бывает 8), в втором случае (`sizeof(*ptr)`) это будет размер всей структуры `privateNumber` (а это как минимум 12 байт).

Comment: а почему именно такая логика?

Comment: ptr - это указатель, так? вот sizeof и возвращает размер указателя.

*ptr - это разыменованный указатель - вот и получаем исходную структуру.

Comment: что пониматся под разименованым указателям структуры? разименование указателя - это значение, но структура трудно понять

Comment: Понятия разыменования указателя (как и собственно указателя) - одно из самых базовых в с/с++. Вы хотите в комментариях получить детальное описание того, что описано в любой книге?

Comment: нет, я пониманию что такое разименование, базы указателей мне понятны (хотя в некоторых местах есть конкретные провалы)

Comment: @MaximPro: Тогда непонятен ваш вопрос. Разыменовыанный указатель и есть структура.

Comment: ну под разименованием указателя понимается получение по адресу значение чего-либо, а что если разименовать указатель на структуру? будет же ошибка?! почему?

Comment: ошибки не будет. Да и не должно быть. Будет просто структура. То есть, можно писать так `ptr->number`, а можно и так `(*ptr).number`. Это одинаково.